# Stackdriver agent in docker container

Tags: bash, docker, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is it possible to set up a generic Docker image with Stackdriver monitoring agents so it can send logging data within the container to Stackdriver, then which can be used across any VM instances regardless of GCE and AWS?

**Update**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

USER root

ADD . /

ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/etc/google/auth/application_default_credentials.json"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install wget curl python-minimal ca-certificates lsb-release libidn11 openssl && \

RUN curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/install-logging-agent.sh
RUN bash install-logging-agent.sh
```

Im exactly following what's been said in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation). The installation goes fine. But google-fluentd is failing to start/restart.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, looking to run stackdriver-agent in a Docker container. Have you figured it out?

Comment: I think that Google Container-Optimized OS Image is not compatible...

Comment: Ubuntu 16 is not in this list https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/ops-agent#linux_operating_systems

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be possible according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/#environments).
You will need to make sure that Stackdriver agent is [installed](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation) and configured correctly in your docker image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I update my question. I'm following exactly what's in the documentation. But it seems to be not working. It's installing without any errors but google-fluentd not starting or restarting.

Comment: Have you followed the verification steps here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/troubleshooting#find-agent-test

Comment: Do you see fluentd when you run ps ax | grep fluentd

Comment: I'm trying something very similar and the docker build is failing installing google-fluentd (1.6.1-1) with:
`invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.`
Is this the fluentd service starting and not being allowed because it's running within `docker build`?

Comment: I got "Unidentifiable or unsupported platform" because the default OS of Google for container is incompatible.